# Net Core 5.0 Web Api 'Some services are not able to be constructed' when trying to set up Google Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a combined windows service/MVC Web API have built in dotNET Core 5.0 which I am trying to add Google Oauth.  Not authenticating directly with a database, not my intension at this point.  Just want to capture the Google claims to do my own authentications on.  However after adding the Google OAuth to the Start function, i get the following error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.)'

Here is my Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<BudgetWorker>().Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                {
                    config.LogName = " Budget";
                    config.SourceName = " Budget";
                });
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                    
            });
}
```

and this is my Startup (which is essentially what comes out of the box as standard in VS2019 when you create a ASP.NET WEB API project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            var clientSecret = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("Resources\\client_secret.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false).Build();
            options.ClientId = clientSecret.GetSection("installed").GetSection("client_id").Value;
            options.ClientSecret = clientSecret.GetSection("installed").GetSection("client_secret").Value;
        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Best I can tell it's getting hung up on the services.AddIdentity() call, and not sure what needs to change?

I have read all the other "related" posts I can find, but nothing sticks out to me as yet.

I suspect it may be something to do with a mix of Singleton/Scoped/Transient services, but this is all new to me, so not sure where to start.

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: installed? which type of client did you create?  Are you following [Google login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0).   Im curious though if this is a web api? How is a user going to consent to the authorization?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, it's the web api component that I am adding to the Google Auth to.  I roughly followed this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jlsHcLJqbk&t=46s
It looks like the user when calling the api should get a request to authenticate, but I can't get to that point.  it crashes when debugging after adding the Google Auth content.

Comment: @DaImTo if you're referring to this part?

var clientSecret = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("Resources\\client_secret.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false).Build();
            options.ClientId = clientSecret.GetSection("installed").GetSection("client_id").Value;
            options.ClientSecret = clientSecret.GetSection("installed").GetSection("client_secret").Value;

That is just a JSON file that houses the Client Secret etc that I was using in another application which I pinched to authenticate with.  Not part of the problem as it doesn't get to that point.

Comment: "Installed" to me implies to me that you created installed credentials on google cloud platform and not web browser credentials.   Please verify that you created [Web browser credentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU)    Installed credentials can not be used with a web application you must create web browser credentials.

Comment: Ah... I'll give that a go.  Yes they were from another non web-browser project.

Comment: @DaImTo created new creds with https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials for a "web application" and set callback url to https://localhost:5001/signin-google  Getting the same System.AggregateException error.

Comment: Did you fix how you are loading your credentials the json file isnt going to be the same format  seriously  read **[THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0)**

Comment: Yes I have read that, I changed my code to clientSecret.GetSection(web:client_id) to match the new json file.  I'm not storing them the same way as that.  I have confirmed it's getting the right values.

I removed the line: services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(); as that didn't seem to have it.  But it just crashes with a different error.

The program '[46808] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

IIS uses a different port, so I added that redirect in google also

Comment: Sorry i cant help with IIS errors.

Comment: To try and just get Oauth working, i created a new test api and now have a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277017/no-webpage-was-found-for-the-web-address-https-localhost44307-signin-google

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237351/discussion-between-devonuto-and-daimto).

Comment: @devonuto did you ever get this working , I am currently working on an electron app with asp.net core backend and I have the login showing but not sure how to redirect the user let me know if you have a solution on how to do that

Comment: @DRW unfortunately, I moved in a different direction and never went back to solve it. But you should be able to set redirect url under  https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

Apologies if that's not what you're after.